# How does Google Compute Engine decide what instances to shut down when autoscaling?

Tags: google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I'm creating a managed instance group with autoscaling in GCE. When a lot of work is queued up new instances will be created which start doing work.

Let's say each chunk of work takes 10 minutes, could it happen that GCE decides to shut down an instance that still has work in progress?

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaler will immediately terminate instance if the health check condition meets.

However, you can use a shutdown script to control the termination. A [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions#preparing_for_instance_terminations) will run, on a [best-effort](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#time_period) basis, in the brief period between when the termination request is made and when the instance is actually terminated. During this period, Compute Engine will attempt to run your shutdown script to perform any tasks you provide in the script. You can read more about the autoscaler decision in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions). You can read about using [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) and its limitation at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#limitations).

Also if these instances are offering backend service then it is good to enable connection draining. You can enable connection draining on backend services to ensure minimal interruption to your users when an instance is deleted automatically by an autoscaler or manually removed from an instance group. You can find more at this link about enabling [connection draining](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/enabling-connection-draining).